# How we distinguish process model and process framework?

Tags: process, cmmi, processmodel

How do we distinguish between process model and process framework (like CMMI). How they relate each other?

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered by distinguishing the terms **model** and **framework**. Do you know the meaning in other contexts? For example, do you know the difference between programming model and programming framework?

To clarify, let's first answer my own question. A model is a more tangible way for describing a concept. But a framework, is a collection of tools, metrics, etc. to make sth. In the context of programming, a programming model is a way you describe your program code. For example, using the imperative programming model, you can describe someone how your program is run. On the other hand, a programming framework, is a collection of debuggers, profilers, compilers, testers, etc. (e.g. .Net Framework) to help you make your programs easier.

The same story is true for processes. A process model is a way you can describe the execution of your process. It may contains its activities, transitions, roles, etc. On the other hand, a process framework, e.g. CMMI, is a collection of goals, practices, sub-practices, CLs, appraisal methods, etc to help you implement a mature process.